# How to mount sdext2 partition by Apps2SD script, before system mount?

Tags: mount, 7.1-nougat, app2sd, resurrection-remix-os

Using Apps2SD Pro app on Samsung Galaxy Note 3 N9005, Resurrection Remix Nougat v5.8.5 with Magisk v17.1.

I lose the linked apps  again & again after reboot. This happened several times already.

I tried all mounting script types, including the advanced one, but after several reboots, the linked apps are disappearing (errors attached). See the Storage screenshot, where you can see the sdext2 (labelled as EXT4) mounted by system, instead by Apps2SD.

The problem is that the sdext2 partition is mounted earlier than the Apps2SD is started and initialized, so Apps2SD can not mount the sdext2 partition, thus the system loses the installed linked apps.

How can I make Apps2SD started before sdext2 partition is mounted by the Resurrection Remix system?

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)

Comment: Don't go for apps, they always dump you ;) If you want more space on internal memory, create a second partition on external sdcard and mount this partition on boot using init.rc. Just add a mount statement after mount_all command (which mounts /data as specified in fstab) to mount sdcard second partition (usually /dev/block/mmcblk1p2) on /data/media or /data/data wherever you want. No need to depend on vold or manage apps individually.

Comment: Thanks! Good idea, to bind the whole /data/data to second partition of external sdcard. But several big apps like Facebook or Chrome becomes very slow on external sdcard. So I have to keep some apps on internal sdcard.

Comment: Use A1 class sdcard, you won't feel even minor differences provided that your host controller is not the limiting factor. UHS3 class also performs good.

Comment: I have Samsung EVO plus 128GB sdcard, which is UHS-I class card. Unfortunately Samsung Galaxy Note 3 N9005 does not support this speed. The internal sdcard is several times faster.

Comment: you may try /data/media instead of /data/data. Data isn't written to internal sdcard that much as on /data/data. However writing larger data to sdcard will be slower but that happens rarely.

Comment: I have only 900 Mb on /data/media compared to several Gb on /data/data, so it would be not really helpful. I really need to make Apps2SD mounting done before the system mount, this would be the real solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon a Magisk module called [fbind](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/fbind) to fix the issue of small internal memory. The module mounts `mmcblk1p2` to `extsd` before Android gets the chance to mount it.

I have been using this module for a couple of days now and it is working perfectly for me. I still occasionally get the soft reboot error but it doesn't do any harm, you always can disable the soft reboot error message from the settings.

Comment: Thanks for getting my attention to the fbind feature. I will try it. However I do not like things, which resultes soft reboot. It means it makes the phone unstable.